# Url duplication with Prestashop SEO

Tags: .htaccess, seo, friendly-url, prestashop

I have an e-commerce developed with the CMS Prestashop.

Yesterday i have seen in my Webmaster Tools that i had some duplicated URL, like this:

```
www.mysite.com/manufacturers
www.mysite.com/it/manufacturers.
```

Where 'it' is the suffix of the default and only language for the website.

I've already activate the friendly URL in the back-office and also I've a .htaccess file generated automatically by the generator in the back-office.

What should I do to fix this issue?

PS: Also I think that I've already taken a penalization from googlebot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere either in the htaccess file in your document root, or in the vhost/server config for **mysite.com**, you'll need to 301 redirect. Now you just need to choose which one you want to keep, the one with `/it/` in front or the one without? Let's say you want to point everything to the one without, you'll use one of these:

Using mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /it/manufacturers /manufacturers
```

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?it/manufacturers(.*)$ /manufacturers$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works fine. I have many pages with this problem. If you can, i need a solution that could work with every page, redirecting every page with the suffix '/it/' at the same without it.

Comment: @Bellu Then just remove all instances of `manufacturers` from either solution

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me clarify the Title from the SEO point of view. The problem is from Prestashop side not from SEO side. It is just affecting your SEO.

Now on the problem, Prestashop is notorious for URL problems. I would not recommend you the .htaccess hack solution because every time you regenerate your .htaccess from you backend, you have to manually insert that hack again in it to keep the problem down. And suppose this url problem arises again after sometime for some other url than you have to do it again. It can turn into a nightmare.

So here are some of my personal recommendations...

1. If this site is critical(which I am assuming), buy a Prestashop url rewriting module from a trusted provider. You will also get a technical support in case this problem arises again in future.
2. If you can't buy than I would suggest you to ask this question on Prestashop forums, as this is Prestashop specific, to permanently solve this problem. You will most likely to get more instant answers as you will find more people working on Prestashop there than here.

Comment: thank you for your sugguestion. I'll buy a module for solve this problem